# Jquery checkbox

Tags: jquery

How to get check box values using jquery map on onclick.

Regards,
Raj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this?

```
<input type="checkbox" class="myCheck" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" class="myCheck" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" class="myCheck" value="3">

<script>
var arr=[];
$('.myCheck').each(
   function (){
      arr.push( $(this).val() );
}
);
</script>
```

the values are in arr variable

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know if the checkbox is checked, you can do :

```
$('#myCheckBox').attr('checked')
```

Comment: i want to retrive all checkbox values.

Comment: maybe some code and the "real" goal you're pursuing will help.

Comment: @raj hot do you want to store data?